# How to not allow admin to create product instance of ProductImpl

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

Basically I wrote two classes which represents product (extending ProductImpl from org.broadleafcommerce...) & added it to all configurations where it was needed.

Now when I click button "Add product" on admin site modal windows displays me a list including Product, ProductBundle, MyProduct1, MyProduct2.

I want to remove Product & ProductBundle (classes from org.broadleafcommerce..) from that list.

Is it possible ? I'm using version 4.0.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can control that by setting the following `AdminPresentation` annotation to your extended class:

`@AdminPresentationClass(ceilingDisplayEntity = "com.mycompany.demo.domain.MyProduct")`

The javadocs on the `ceilingDisplayEntity` say:

> By specifying a class lower in the inheritance hierarchy, you can cause only a subset of the entire JPA inheritance hierarchy to be presented to the user as options when creating new entities. This value will override any previous settings for this inheritance hierarchy

Comment: I'm so stupid... i missed it reading docs of this adnotation. I only realize that there is parametr which excludes it from polymorphic but I cant override it.